# Перебор содержимого объекта (ключей и значений свойств) в цикле

Tags: javascript

Просьба подсказать, как корректно перебрать подобную конструкцию для дальнейшей работы с ней.
Пытаюсь перебрать для сборки аккордеона, где `<AB>` будет являться `title` а `["DC: 4564", "Acbg", "Ty: 9878"]` будет заполнять скрытый `content`

```
let response_js = [{
  "<AB>": ["DC: 4564", "Acbg", "Ty: 9878"],
  "<GH>": ["Ty: 4987", "Okub", "Olu: 0888"],
}];
```

Comment: По ходу дела: JSON - это всегда строка как способ хранения и передачи данных (в том числе массивов и объектов). У вас же просто массив с объектом, тут JSON  совершенно не при чём)

Comment: Да, объект в массиве всегда один. Да, нужно перебрать ключи и значения,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если объект в массиве всегда один, перебрать его ключи и значения можно при помощи цикла [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) и [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), используя [деструктуризацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const response_js = [{
  "<AB>": ["DC: 4564", "Acbg", "Ty: 9878"],
  "<GH>": ["Ty: 4987", "Okub", "Olu: 0888"],
}];

for (const [title, content] of Object.entries(response_js[0])) {
  console.log(title);
  console.log(content);
}
```